# Getting 404 Error Page Not Found in Nextjs v14.1.0

Tags: next.js

I want to navigate from home page, from the header section to Login page and Register page. I am getting the Error immediately clicking on either of the two.
The folder structure I have is:
src
...app
......layout folder
Footer.jsx
Header.jsx
......login folder
Login.js
......register folder
Register.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Link from "next/link";
import Image from 'next/image'

const Header = () => {
  return (
      <>
      <header className="flex items-center justify-between">
        <nav className="flex items-center gap-8 text-gray-500 font-semibold">
        <Link className="text-primary font-semibold text-2xl" href='/'>
          <Image 
            src={'/ruana.png'} 
            objectFit={'contain'}
            height={130}  
            width={130}
            alt={'logo'}
            className='rounded-full'
          />
        </Link>
          <Link href={'/'}>Home</Link>
          <Link href={''}>Menu</Link>
          <Link href={''}>About</Link>
          <Link href={''}>Contact</Link>
        </nav>
        <nav className='flex items-center gap-4 text-gray-500 font-semibold'>
          <Link href='/login' >Login</Link>
          <Link href='/register' className="bg-primary text-white rounded-full px-8 py-2">Register</Link>
        </nav>
      </header>
     </>
  )
}

export default Header
```

Comment: Can you please share if you are using a page router vs app router?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your folder structure is as follows:

```js
src
|-- app
    |-- layout
        |-- Header.jsx
    |-- login
        |-- Login.js
    |-- register
        |-- Register.js
```

Make sure the paths specified in href match the actual file paths in your project. Also, ensure that the Login and Register components are correctly implemented in their respective files (Login.js and Register.js). If there are errors in those components, it might cause issues when navigating to them.

Comment: Thanks. I have actually solved the error. I think the naming convention is quite unique in Next.js. I changed the Login.js and Register.js to page.jsx, each in their respective folders.